# I have a problem with receiving messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make my app recieve notifications but i've tried many times to make this work but nothing I tried works. At the moment I have the code below but if I send a message via Firebase self the message doesn't display on my phone or an emeulator.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        //Retrieve the firebaseMessage
        getFirebaseMessage(message.getNotification().getTitle(), message.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void getFirebaseMessage(String title, String body) {
        //Build notification for display
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "post")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(102, builder.build());
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea of what I did wrong please let me know